# List in columns layout depending on viewport width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-multicolumn-layout

How can I make **several columns from one list** with *CSS*?
The number of columns must change depending on the screen width with media queries as shown here :

**lage screen:**

```
Row1 Row6  Row11
Row2 Row7  Row12
Row3 Row8  Row13
Row4 Row9  Row14
Row5 Row10
```

**middle screen:**

```
Row1 Row8
Row2 Row9
Row3 Row10
Row4 Row11
Row5 Row12
Row6 Row13
Row7 Row14
```

**small screen:**

```
Row1
Row2
Row3
Row4
Row5
Row6
Row7
Row8
Row9
Row10
Row11
Row12
Row13
Row14
```

Here is my *HTML* code :

```
<ul>
  <li>Row1</li>
  <li>Row2</li>
  <li>Row3</li>
  <li>Row4</li>
  <li>Row5</li>
  <li>Row6</li>
  <li>Row7</li>
  <li>Row8</li>
  <li>Row9</li>
  <li>Row10</li>
  <li>Row11</li>
  <li>Row12</li>
  <li>Row13</li>
  <li>Row14</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [`CSS multi-column layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts). Just to add [`support`](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count) isn't the best.

Or if you can set fixed height on `ul` you could use **Flexbox** and `flex-direction: column;` like this **[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/sybvz499/2/)** but its not really "flexible" solution.

```css
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
   column-count: 3;
   list-style-type: none;
}

@media(max-width: 992px) {
  ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
     column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
     column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Row1</li>
  <li>Row2</li>
  <li>Row3</li>
  <li>Row4</li>
  <li>Row5</li>
  <li>Row6</li>
  <li>Row7</li>
  <li>Row8</li>
  <li>Row9</li>
  <li>Row10</li>
  <li>Row11</li>
  <li>Row12</li>
  <li>Row13</li>
  <li>Row14</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) combined with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to change the number of columns based on viewport width.

In the following example the columns change from 3 to 2 when the viewport is 700px wide and from 2 to 1 when the viewport is 500px wide.
Note that you **don't need to specify anything for narrow viewport** as the one column display is the default layout and only specify `columns` starting on what you called "middle screen":

```css
@media (min-width: 500px){  
  ul{
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px){  
  ul{
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Row1</li>
  <li>Row2</li>
  <li>Row3</li>
  <li>Row4</li>
  <li>Row5</li>
  <li>Row6</li>
  <li>Row7</li>
  <li>Row8</li>
  <li>Row9</li>
  <li>Row10</li>
  <li>Row11</li>
  <li>Row12</li>
  <li>Row13</li>
  <li>Row14</li>
</ul>
```

*Note that the the columns property needs vendor prefixed to maximize browser support, it is supported by IE10+ (more info on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)).*

Answer (score 1):

This a simple solution but more accepted on old browsers.

You can divide the LI's by adjusting their size and displaying them as inline-block.

In this case, 4 columns 25% width each Li, when the screen is larger than 768px and 2 columns when the screen is smaller than 768px. (you can add as many media queries as you want)

```css
li {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -2px;
  }

@media (max-width: 768px){  
  li{
        width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Row1</li>
  <li>Row2</li>
  <li>Row3</li>
  <li>Row4</li>
  <li>Row5</li>
  <li>Row6</li>
  <li>Row7</li>
  <li>Row8</li>
  <li>Row9</li>
  <li>Row10</li>
  <li>Row11</li>
  <li>Row12</li>
  <li>Row13</li>
  <li>Row14</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do what the OP asked for.